# Disable tax for non logged in users

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, tax

In WooCommerce, I'm trying to apply `set_is_vat_exempt()` method for customer **and guest user**.

For logged customer it is working fine. Can anyone suggest how can I do it?

One issue could be like as the user is not logged in so may be `$woocommerce->customer` could not enable it.

Here's my code:

```
$bilalId = get_current_user_id();

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_order_total_html', 'wc_cart_totals_order_total_html_bn');

function wc_cart_totals_order_total_html_bn() {
    global $woocommerce;

     if( current_user_can('customer' || $bilalId == 0) ) {

              $woocommerce->customer->set_is_vat_exempt(true);

         } 

}
```

At the end, I just want to disable any tax rates for non-logged in user.

even I tried "Zero rate" but doesn't worked for me.

Any kind of guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So what you need is to use the wordpress conditional [**`is_user_logged_in()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) in a custom function hooked in **`init`** action hook, this way:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wc_tax_exempt_unlogged' );
function wc_tax_exempt_unlogged() {

    // Getting user data for logged users
    if( is_user_logged_in() ){
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $current_user_id = $current_user->ID;
        $current_user_roles = $current_user->roles;
        $bilal_id = 0;
    }

    // Exempting of VAT non logged users, customers and the main admin ID (you)
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() || in_array( 'customer', $current_user_roles ) || $bilal_id == $current_user_id ){
        WC()->customer->set_is_vat_exempt(true);
    }
}
```

*The Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.

Comment: @BilalHussain I have tested and it works for me on my test server… This code remove the tax from the cart totals and in checkout totals.

Comment: Is this could be the theme issue? Working perfect if i once open the checkout page. But after clearing cache again showing the wrong?

Comment: set_is_vat_exempt() on null .............
getting this error when no user logged in, any suggestion?